# How can I remove unused chunks from MUI in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, next.js, frontend

[image]

I have created a single page but getting a large size of unused javascript. I am using MUI and React icons.

How to handle it?

I was trying to dynamically import those mui components and react icons by hoping to handle the unused JavaScript. But It didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with MUI icons in particular causing large bundle sizes, because out-of-the-box, all of the icons end up included in the project. I suggest reading the MUI docs on:

- Managing bundle size https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/
- And specifically for icons https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/

This also changes across versions, and I'm not sure which version of MUI you are using, but see for example an old thread on tree-shaking for v4: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/10857

Comment: So for the big projects do i use MUI icons? From the document which you gave me I found MUI icons is difficult to handle. So can I use images as buttons? Is it ok?

Comment: One of the reasons I've started using either a custom icon generator that I made ([here](https://github.com/brandonscript/mui-custom-svg-icons) - caveat: probably a little out of date, maybe I should update it ) or [react-icons](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/).